# taxamo checkout throws currency_code validation error

Tags: magento2, checkout, api

```
**taxamo api checkout form integration into magento 2.x** :
```

I am using taxamo api
    checkout form in magento 2.x. below is code. but
    throws error :

> "Validation failed {:transaction {:currency_code missing-required-key}}" error

```
Taxamo.initialize('public key');                   
Taxamo.setCurrencyCode('USD');                                        
Taxamo.scanPrices();    
Taxamo.detectButtons();    
Taxamo.detectCountry(); 



var transaction = { custom_fields: [{key: "untaxed-plan-id", value: "taxamo_untaxed"},
                    {key: "taxed-plan-id", value: "taxamo_taxed"}],currency_code: "USD",
                    billing_country_code: Taxamo.defaultTransaction.billing_country_code};



var metadata    = { allowed_payment_providers: 'braintree,paypal',
subscription_mode: true,
require_email: true,
show_buyer_name: true,
show_invoice_address: true,
finished_redirect_url: self.location.href
};

var checkout = new Taxamo.Checkout(transaction, metadata);
checkout.overlay(function(data) 
{ 
//you can also use .redirect() here
alert('callbackhandler:' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));               
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set plan ids from your Braintree account that is connected with your Taxamo account instead of using "taxamo_taxed" and "taxamo_untaxed" ( which are plan ids that work with Taxamo's test account mentioned in Taxamo Checkout form [documentation](https://www.taxamo.com/doc/taxamojs/checkout/)). Depending on the Taxamo public keys you are using (test or live) for Checkout form initialization you need to use appropriate plan ids from Braintree, Sandbox or Production.